Increased, higher pitch rolling noise after tire change
I recently changed my tires from 32mm Continental Grand Prix 5000s (clincher variant) to 44mm Rene Herse Snoqualmie Pass TC Extralights, which make a significantly louder, higher pitched, and more annoying sound when rolling on pavement. Given how little tread they have, why would these new tires make so much more noise? Is there anything I can do to reduce the noise? Will the noise reduce naturally as I ride more?
There's plenty of frame clearance, I'm running above the "soft" tire pressure recommendation give by Rene Herse tire pressure calculator's, there's no brake rotor rub, and I don't notice the sound when the bike is on the stand. Rene Herse support confirmed that I did not install the tires backwards, and that they're "not sure why" I'm having this issue. Given how expensive these tires were, I was hoping for more support from Rene Herse .
My bike weighs around 25 lbs, I weigh around 175 lbs, and all riding was done on pavement. The following table compares the tire differences




Continental GP 5000 Clincher
Rene Herse Snoqualmie Pass TC Extralights




width
32 mm
44 mm


pressure
55 psi
50 psi


tubes
RideNow Ultralight TPU tubes, 18-32c
RideNow Ultralight Gravel TPU tubes 32-47c




The GP5000 is totally smooth on the centre line and for most of the contact patch. I can't find a decent picture of the tread of your new one but it looks like there's some texture (you may want to take a picture yourself and add it).
In other words, little tread is very different from no tread.
The chances are it's not going to go away. As the tyre rolls, it deforms a little, but I reckon the high pitched noise is due to air being almost but not quite trapped between the tyre and the road, and hissing as it escapes.
You must have very fine road surfaces for it to make much difference, because even slick tyres press air into voids in the paving and make a noise that way. A particularly smooth top surface will be quite different to one that's more porous for drainage. You must also have very quiet riding conditions for it to be consistently audible above the background - even a gentle breeze in the trees drowns out anything less than gravel tyres on roads; the wind of your own motion in your ears can have the same effect if you're going fast - I reckon you are with those choices.
You can experiment with the pressure, but there are more important variables to optimise that for. I know with my gravel tyres on mixed surface rides they're quieter road-hard than after letting some air out for an off-road stretch, but that hard and the ride becomes harsh on all but the best roads, and the grip on wet paving suffers (nothing fancy, just WTB Riddler).

Unfortunately, my road surface is super uneven, cracked, and generally bumpy, hence the switch to wider tires.

@peachy you can go wider without (much of) a tread pattern, and what there is  could be quite a bit quieter. Here's a review of some options. But I run 32 or 35 on  some really rough roads, and a little off road. Even my gravel tyres are only 37 (though I'll fit something slightly bigger when I wear them out)

I'm under the impression that the compound is as important as the tread pattern when it comes to noise (and maybe the structure as well).
The noisiest tires (on tarmac) I have in my rotation are in fact semi-slicks (Michelin Power Adventure, allroad tire - the noise is also mentioned in some reviews), and are noisier than "knobby gravel" tires (Michelin Power Gravel, that uses a different compound but with knobs). To nuance, the Power Gravel are quieter at low speed but produce a turbine-like noise at higher speeds. FWIW, the quietest tires in my rotation are also semi-slicks (Hutchinson Caracal Race), so hard to draw conclusions from this very limited sample.
But as pointed out by @ChrisH, I would also experiment with pressure, I also have the impression that higher pressures are noisier. And also, 50 psi seems like a lot for 44mm high performance tires: according to Silca's calculator, pressures should be a bit lower than 40psi.

You've got me wondering if the shape of the tread pattern is more relevant than I thought. Little cells would behave very differently to well-spaced chunks of rubber, both in the way they deform and how air flows round them

@ChrisH to compare the two semi-slicks of my sample, the casing is very different: the Michelin is quite puncture resistant, while the Hutchinson is a race tire, very supple, but not puncture resistant.

BTW I'd expect the Power Adventure to be quite sensitive to pressure, with the noise coming back at low pressures as the shoulder tread makes more contact with the road

@ChrisH The tread is indeed important.

If the bike is silent on the stand we can rule out all possible sources based on wheel rubbing anythink.
So we are left with tyre-road contact.
The nose is caused by periodical impacts between the tyre and the road nad is amplified by a resonator (Every ellastic thing has its natural frequency and when it's forced to oscillate, the amplitude increases over time).
I would suspect the thread pattern to be the source of the induced oscillations. The resonator can be the tyre wall, rims and spokes or loose bearings.
Does the tone and intensity change with the different speed? You can try meddling with the tyre pressure - it changes the ellastic and damping properties. You can check the spokes tension whether there might be some problem too.
The noise can originate from spokes oscillating and either hitting each other or scratching.

As well as the tread pattern (some little relief vs slick on the Conti's), won't the size of the contact patch matter? You are running a larger tire at lower pressures so the contact patch is larger and that means more interactions between the tire and the road surface and hence, more noise.
